# Get most recently created list item with MS FLow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, getlist

I am new to Flow and want to use it to retrieve a single list item and copy it's contents to another list on a different site. I have found many guides explaining haw to retrieve all the items in a list but I only want the most recently created one (the item whose creation triggered the flow)

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this in baby-steps as this is my first attempt at using Flow instead of SharePoint Workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flow, there's an "Get item" action. You could use it to get the most recently created one.

1.Create a flow, choose the trigger "When an item is created"

[image]

2.Then in the next step, choose the "Get item" action. Note: Make sure you choose get item instead of get items.
[image]

3. In the action, choose the list and ID

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will already get reference of current item when trigger point is item created. Use dynamic content in next action

Ref link -https://youtu.be/8-3bxdnv35c